# C# Server issue when receiving packets too fast

Tags: c#, ftp, server

So i'm having an issue with a server/client application i'm writing to send files from the server to the client.

When sending a file on the server end, there is a loop to send buffers up to 16kb until the full file is sent.

When the client is receiving the file, it receives the files in buffers up to 16kb at a time until it gets the full file.

Here's the weird part. I think it is maybe a property I have set wrong to be causing my issue. If I put a sleep on the client's receiving end loop of 5ms, it works fine (on my local pc). Every file will go through without an issue. If there is no sleep timer, sometimes the file transfer will work, and other times a packet will get corrupted in the middle of a transfer.

I had a friend try running the client to see if it would work for them with the 5ms sleep. The problem is for them we had to actually raise the sleep timer to avoid getting corrupted packets. We ended up raising the sleep timer to 100ms and found that every file could be successfully transferred this way, but the problem is the speed is so slow.

Does anyone know what could be causing this ghost?

In case anyone is interested in the send method as well as the receive method, here they are

```
public bool SendFile(string SendFilePath, string ActualFilePath)
{
    //First send packet to start sending file
    try
    {
        if (!SendInt32((Int32)PacketType.StartUpdate))
            return false;
        if (!SendString(SendFilePath))
            return false;
        if (!GetInt32(out packettype))
            return false;
        if (packettype != (Int32)PacketType.ConfirmationPacket)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0x0 Expected Confirmation Packet, but instead received: " + packettype);
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        clientSocket.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Error upon attempting to send 'Start File Update' packet.");
        return false;
    }

    //Next send the file
    BinaryReader FileToSend = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ActualFilePath));
    int FileSize = (int)FileToSend.BaseStream.Length;
    int FileOffset = 0;
    int RemainingSize = (FileSize - FileOffset);
    byte[] filebuffer = new byte[MaxPacketSize];
    while (RemainingSize > 0)
    {
        if (RemainingSize >= MaxPacketSize)
        {
            FileToSend.Read(filebuffer, 0, MaxPacketSize);
            if (!SendInt32((Int32)PacketType.ByteBuffer))
                return false;
            if (!SendByteArray(filebuffer, MaxPacketSize))
                return false;
            FileOffset += MaxPacketSize;
            RemainingSize = (FileSize-FileOffset);
        }
        else
        {
            FileToSend.Read(filebuffer, 0, RemainingSize);
            if (!SendInt32((Int32)PacketType.ByteBuffer))
                return false;
            if (!SendByteArray(filebuffer, RemainingSize))
                return false;
            FileOffset += RemainingSize;
            RemainingSize = (FileSize - FileOffset);
        }
        //Get confirmation packet before sending another packet
        if (!GetInt32(out packettype))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (packettype != (Int32)PacketType.ConfirmationPacket)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0x2 Expected Confirmation Packet - received: " + packettype);
        }
    }
    FileToSend.Close();


    //Next send packet to stop updating this file
    try
    {
        if (!SendInt32((Int32)PacketType.StopUpdate))
            return false;
        if (!GetInt32(out packettype))
            return false;
        if (packettype != (Int32)PacketType.ConfirmationPacket)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0x1 Expected Confirmation Packet, but instead received: " + packettype);
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        clientSocket.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Error upon attempting to send 'Stop File Update' packet.");
        return false;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("File Sent:" + SendFilePath);
    return true;
}
```

The client calls ReceiveFile after the StartUpdate packet is received.

```
public bool ReceiveFile(string rootdir)
{
    //First get the FilePath
    try
    {
        if (!GetString(out FilePath)) //If failure to receive a string packet
            return false; //crash
        Console.WriteLine("Root Dir: "+rootdir+" File Path:" + FilePath);
        if (!SendInt32((Int32)PacketType.ConfirmationPacket)) //If failure to send an int packet
            return false; //crash
    }
    catch
    {
        clientSocket.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Error upon attempting to send 'Start File Update' packet.");
        return false; //crash
    }

    //Next receive the file
    BinaryWriter ReceivedFile = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(rootdir + "\\" +FilePath));
    int FileOffset = 0;
    byte[] filebuffer;
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (!GetInt32(out packettype))
            return false;
        if (packettype != (Int32)PacketType.ByteBuffer && packettype != (Int32)PacketType.StopUpdate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected byte buffer or stop update packet. Received: " + packettype);
            return false;
        }
        if (packettype == (Int32)PacketType.StopUpdate)
        {
            if (!SendInt32((int)PacketType.ConfirmationPacket))
                return false;
            break;
        }
        if (packettype == (Int32)PacketType.ByteBuffer)
        {
            int arraysize;
            if (!GetByteArray(out filebuffer, out arraysize))
                return false;
            ReceivedFile.Write(filebuffer, 0, arraysize);
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
            FileOffset += arraysize;
            if (!SendInt32((int)PacketType.ConfirmationPacket))
                return false;
        }
    }
    ReceivedFile.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("File Received: " + FilePath);
    Console.WriteLine("File Size: " + ((FileOffset / 1024) + 1).ToString() + " KB");
    return true;
}
```

Edit: Also, MaxPacketSize = 16384

Comment: The problem is probably in the implementation of the GetByteArray method. Can you please share it?

Comment: Because you are sending a packet type (4 bytes) and then the buffer (16384 bytes), then the next packet type then the next buffer again, while the TCP communication has it's own buffer mechanism and thus combined packets (both buffer and the packet type) can be sent as a single packet or even a buffer can be sent partially which will cause the client to run into trouble. That's also why issuing a sleep MAY help because in that case the packets might be sent with the buffer sizes you desire.

Comment: Can you try to set TcpClient.NoDelay to true on the server side? Remove the sleep and give it a try. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GetByteArray, make sure you are obtaining all of the bytes for one packet. The [NetworkStream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) function returns the number of bytes that were read, so make sure that is equal to the number of bytes you are expecting. If not, call it again until you have enough. Just make sure to update your offset and number of bytes left. For example, if you've received 10 bytes already, you should receive starting at index 10, and only receive buffersize-10 bytes (so you don't overflow).